# How do I show column type Date/Time in VB GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am using a Database in Access 2010. And using visual studio 2005.
I have data in a column of type "Date/Time" like this:

[image]

And I show it in Gridview by

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DATE" SortExpression="date_request">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label_DATE" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date_request") %>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TIME" SortExpression="time_request">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label_TIME" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("time_request") %>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then it displays like this:
[image]

I don't know why it is not showing the same as my database.
Could someone show me how to make trhem display the same?

Comment: to Chase Ernst : Thank you for edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all of the above code with the following  code.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="date_request" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Date" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="time_request" DataFormatString="{0:t}" HeaderText="Time" />
```

Or use the below code

```
Text='<%# Bind("date_request", "{0:d}") %>'
Text='<%# Bind("time_request", "{0:t}") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it back into a `BoundField`, and then use `DataFormatString` to display the datetime values using the following link to build your format:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Explore the properties of gridview.